# Is there anyway to do this faster and with less code? Intermediate

Tags: php, sql, oop, insert

```
class Useradd {
function insert_user_into_database($user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_email) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email) 
            VALUES ('$user_firstname', '$user_lastname', '$user_email')";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
}
}



$user_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$user_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


$useradd = new Useradd;
$useradd->insert_user_into_database($user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_email);
```

Comment: Why would you try to add a row whose column names were the same as the values you passed to it?  Is that a typo having the `$` prefix in the first group?

Comment: What is the purpose of the Class here. If you do away with the class you will have less code. But considering that this is the fastest this can be.

Comment: One more thing you can do is use mysqli or PDO to create prepared statements so that consecutive calls to the query will be faster between php and mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `insert_user_into_database` function static, so that you don't have to create an instance of the `Useradd` object just to insert a new user:

```
class Useradd {
    static function insert_user_into_database($user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_email) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Useradd::insert_user_into_database($user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_email);
```

Comment: Yes, this is an improvement if he needs to have an object.  IIRC it's normal function > static method > instance method... so, still an improvement.

Comment: Also if you're feeling frisky you could execute your `mysql_real_escape_string` calls inline with the insert user function call, instead of creating a variable to hold their output.  `Useradd::insert_user_into_database(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));`

Comment: Actually, I take that last comment back, you should do the escaping inside of your function and just pass it the raw strings.  That way you can call it from other places and you know your values will always be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

Faster code and reduced lines is not something you should be concerned about when looking at the code above.

- Not proper OOP design: A class isn't just a wrapper for a function
- The sanitization should be internalized to the class
- mysql_real_escape_string isn't always the right choice to sanitize inputs
- Your method does nothing with the result, that's never good.

So, really, the best answer is to say, "You need to add a lot to that code."

If someone's telling you the best programs are the shortest, they're an idiot. If someone tells you the longest programs are the best, they're an idiot also. The best programming does exactly what it needs to do, and exactly what should happen. Trying to put everything into one-liners or make it run as fast as it can leads to a lot of problems, especially when you need to maintain that code a month later.

Comment: I... must have gotten something in the eye... That last part of your answer needs upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

Is the class necessary?  There is no advantage in this case to declaring a class, instantiating it, and then calling a class method; just create a normal function and execute that.